# "Back to school" as an adjective or noun

Tags: nouns, compound-adjectives, attributive-nouns

What would be a good noun to call a person who deliberately, willfully makes a "back to school" trip to get a refresher on a subject (like geometry, calculus, biology)? Humorous nouns and expressions accepted.

Examples of intended usage:

- *I am a ... in calculus.*
- *She has been a ... in biology recently - she decided she needed a refresher in animals taxonomy.*

A *late student* would sound a bit like an obituary. Not sure.

*Not even sure I phrased my question correctly - "back to school" is a difficult idea to convey within a sentence.*

Comment: ...maybe a "_returning_ student"? But [that definition](https://www.colum.edu/admissions/requirements/returning-students) is pretty narrow at most Unis.

Comment: I was going to suggest “refresher”, a pun on “fresher” which is the UK term for a first year university student.  In the US, I believe “freshman” is used, so “refreshman” might work if that’s where you’re based.  Or “sophomore and more”.

Comment: @Cascabel I like it! despite its specific definition. I would add "a happy returning student" to perhaps lighten it up - otherwise it sounds a bit as if the student was told/obliged to return.